# Android Project to Github repository

Tags: git, github, gradle

I have this settings.gradle:

include ':appbase', ':app1', ':app2', ':app3'

project(': appbase').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../AppBase/appbase')

When I try to bring my project to GitHub repository only modules app1 app2 app3 are on VCS but not the module appbase

Any help?

Comment: in which directory did you do initialize git i.e, `git init`?

Comment: Show us your directory scructure including `.git` dir. It's not an android problem, git only

Comment: please gitignore file too.

Comment: I'm new to Android Studio. To bring project to VCS i did the following from menu: VCS > Import Into Version Control > Share Project on GitHub

Comment: Definitely `appbase` module folder is located outside of project root or has it's own .git inside. To give a correct answer we need to know your project structure. Otherwise take a look at `git`, `git submodules`.

Comment: My appbase is located outside of project root. Thanks